# python importing csv header into a dict

Tags: python, csv

How does one import the header of a file into a dict.

I've tried this but it imports the whole dict:

```
import csv
d = csv.DictReader('foo.csv', dialect='excel', delimiter=',')
```

Is that even possible?

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by this. Could you show an example of what you would want the generated data structure to look like?

Comment: First param should be an open file handle, not file name: `d = csv.DictReader(open('foo.csv'), dialect='excel', delimiter=',')` to update your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are doing will work fine.

`d.fieldnames` contains a list of field names

I think `DictReader` just wraps the file object.  So although you can iterate through the whole csv it is not 'imported' into memory.